# Filter rows based one column' value and calculate percentage of sum in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
   value  input
0      3      0
1      4      1
2      3     -1
3      2      1
4      3     -1
5      5      0
6      1      0
7      1      1
8      1      1
```

I have used the following code:

```
df['pct'] = df['value'] / df['value'].sum()
```

But I want to calculate `pct` by excluding `input = -1`, which means if `input` value is `-1`, then the correspondent values will not taken into account to sum up, neither necessary to calculate `pct`, for rows `2` and `4` at this case.

The expected result will like this:

```
   value  input   pct
0      3      0  0.18
1      4      1  0.24
2      3     -1   NaN
3      2      1  0.12
4      3     -1   NaN
5      5      0  0.29
6      1      0  0.06
7      1      1  0.06
8      1      1  0.06
```

How could I do that in Pandas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum not matched rows by missing values to Series `s` by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and divide only rows not matched mask filtered by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), last round by [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
mask = df['input'] != -1
df.loc[mask, 'pct'] = (df.loc[mask, 'value'] / df['value'].where(mask).sum()).round(2)

print (df)
   value  input   pct
0      3      0  0.18
1      4      1  0.24
2      3     -1   NaN
3      2      1  0.12
4      3     -1   NaN
5      5      0  0.29
6      1      0  0.06
7      1      1  0.06
8      1      1  0.06
```

EDIT: If need replace missing values to `0` is possible use second argument in `where` for set values to `0`, this `Series` is possible also `sum` for same output like replace to missing values:

```
s = df['value'].where(df['input'] != -1, 0)
df['pct'] = (s / s.sum()).round(2)

print (df)
   value  input   pct
0      3      0  0.18
1      4      1  0.24
2      3     -1  0.00
3      2      1  0.12
4      3     -1  0.00
5      5      0  0.29
6      1      0  0.06
7      1      1  0.06
8      1      1  0.06
```

Comment: Thanks, if I need to fill `NaN` with `0`?