# Groupby multiple columns and calculate percentage of sums in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given a dataset `df` as follows:

```
  type module   item  value  input
0    A      a  item1      2      1
1    A      a  item2      3      0
2    A     aa  item3      4      1
3    A     aa  item4      3      0
4    A     aa  item5      1     -1
5    B      b  item1      5      0
6    B      b  item2      1     -1
7    B     bb  item3      3      0
8    B     bb  item4      3      1
9    B     bb  item5      4      0
```

I need to calculate `sum` of `pct` based on the following logic: first, we only take `value` whose `input` is `0` or `1` as valid values. Then I need to groupby `type, module` to calculate percentage of sum, for example, the `pct` of first row of `A-a-item1` is calculated by `2/(2 + 3) = 0.4`, `A-aa-item1` is calculated by `4/(4 + 3) = 0.57`, not divided by `8` since input value for `A-aa-item3` is `-1` so it's excluded. The `sum` column in `df2` is calculated by groupby `type module` then sum of `sum`.

**df1:**

```
  type module   item  value  input       pct 
0    A      a  item1      2      1  0.400000
1    A      a  item2      3      0  0.000000 
2    A     aa  item1      4      1  0.571429 
3    A     aa  item2      3      0  0.000000 
4    A     aa  item3      1     -1  0.000000 
5    B      b  item1      5      0  0.000000 
6    B      b  item2      1     -1  0.000000 
7    B     bb  item1      3      0  0.000000 
8    B     bb  item2      3      1  0.300000 
9    B     bb  item3      4      0  0.000000
```

**df2:**

```
  type module   sum
0    A      a  0.40
1    A     aa  0.57
2    B      b  0.00
3    B     bb  0.30
```

How could I get similar results based on the given dataset? Thanks.

Comment: So there are 2 masks - first compare for equal `0` or `1` and then for compare by `1`, so rows with `-1, 0`  are set to `0` in `pct`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace not matched by conditions with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for compare by `1` with `0` and compare by `0, 1`  by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and instead aggregation is used [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for new column filled by aggregate values and divided by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) :

```
s1 = df['value'].where(df['input'].eq(1), 0)
s2 = (df.assign(value = df['value'].where(df['input'].isin([0,1]), 0))
        .groupby(['type','module'])['value'].transform('sum'))
df['pct '] = s1.div(s2)
print (df)
  type module   item  value  input      pct 
0    A      a  item1      2      1  0.400000
1    A      a  item2      3      0  0.000000
2    A     aa  item3      4      1  0.571429
3    A     aa  item4      3      0  0.000000
4    A     aa  item5      1     -1  0.000000
5    B      b  item1      5      0  0.000000
6    B      b  item2      1     -1  0.000000
7    B     bb  item3      3      0  0.000000
8    B     bb  item4      3      1  0.300000
9    B     bb  item5      4      0  0.000000
```

For second `DataFrame` is added 2 new columns by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), aggregate `sum` and last divide with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and remove column `value`:

```
df2 = (df.assign(value = df['value'].where(df['input'].isin([0,1]), 0),
                 pct = df['value'].where(df['input'].eq(1), 0))
         .groupby(['type','module'])[['value','pct']]
         .sum()
         .assign(pct = lambda x: x['pct'].div(x.pop('value')))
         .reset_index())

print (df2)
  type module       pct
0    A      a  0.400000
1    A     aa  0.571429
2    B      b  0.000000
3    B     bb  0.300000
```

Comment: Sorry, I found a small problem in your code, as I posted in last question, when we calculate `pct` for `df`, we need to exclude values of `input=-1` from the sums.

Comment: @xarena - output is different in question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989116/filter-rows-based-one-column-value-and-calculate-percentage-of-sum-in-pandas. I need to implent this after groupby also.

Comment: @xarena - So you need change `pct = df['value'].where(df['input'].eq(1), 0)` to `pct = df['value'].where(df['input'] != -1, 0)` ?

Comment: I test with my real data, it seems the problem from `s2` which didn't sucessfully exclude values of `input=-1` when sum up. It's quite weird.

Comment: @xarena - Not sure if understand, there is no 2 different conditions for compare?

Comment: @xarena - Mainly do you need set to 0 all rows if `input` values are `0,-1` ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, your code is perfect, I have mischanged `value` to another name, but in some code it keeps.